# Display Bootstrap Buttons in different forms and other elements to be inline

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to display two buttons (Save and Delete) inline and while there are quite a few similar questions on here, none of those solutions worked for me.

I'm suspicious it is because my forms have so much going on in them.
I tried using `style="float:left; width: auto"` to no avail.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
<form id="roadmapR" method="post" action="/roadmap/save.html" style="float:left; width: auto">
  <input type="hidden" class="roadmapData" name="roadmapData" value="">
  <table id="roadmapTable">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>126 Errors Found. <span id="rowErrors"></span> rows have errors.  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Show Errors <input type="checkbox" id="showErrors" checked></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div id="errors" class="hot handsontable htRowHeaders htColumnHeaders"style="height: 220px; overflow: hidden; width: 1400px;" data-originalstyle="height: 220px; overflow: hidden; width: 1000px;"></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="left"><input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search Roadmap for..." required> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Filter Roadmap to only show errors <input type="checkbox" id="showRoadmapErrors">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
          <table id="filterTable">
            <tr>
              <td align="left">
                <table id="filterResetTable">
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <button id="resetBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-roadmap" >Reset</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <button id="filterBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-roadmap" >Filter</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="form-filter">
                  <select name="filter1_category" id="filter1_category">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                  </select>
                  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  <select multiple name="filter1_value" id="filter1_value">
                  </select>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="form-filter">
                  <select name="filter2_category" id="filter2_category">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                  </select>
                  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  <select multiple name="filter2_value" id="filter2_value">
                  </select>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="form-filter">
                  <select name="filter3_category" id="filter3_category">
                    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select Your Filter...</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                  </select>
                  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  <select multiple name="filter3_value" id="filter3_value">
                  </select>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td>
              &nbsp;
              </td></tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>Your Roadmap Information, 40 total rows; <span id="filterCount"></span> filter rows:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-roadmap  saveChanges" style="height:42px" disabled>Save</button>
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p><span id="fatalErrorMessage" style="color:red;"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
<form id="roadmapD" method="post" action="/roadmap/delete.html" style="float:left; width: auto">
  <input type="hidden" class="deleteData" name="deleteData" value="">
  <table id="roadmapGridTable">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-roadmap deleteChanges"  style="height:42px" enabled>Delete</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div id="tableTotals" class="hot handsontable htRowHeaders htColumnHeaders"style="height: 2000px; overflow: hidden; width: 3000px; " data-originalstyle="height: 220px; overflow: hidden; width: 900px; "></div><div id="dialog" title="Error Found"><p></p></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Here's a jfiddle to what I have https://jsfiddle.net/hs239zfo/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your buttons aren't in the same "container" element...
There is no way to postion them inline without changing your HTML markup.

Try this:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <p>Your Roadmap Information, 40 total rows; <span id="filterCount"></span> filter rows:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-roadmap  saveChanges" style="height:42px" disabled>Save</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-roadmap deleteChanges"  style="height:42px" enabled>Delete</button>
    </p>
  </td>
</tr>
```

And this function to submit the right `form`:

```
$(".saveChanges").on("click",function(){
  alert("The form with id 'roadmapR' is submitting.");
  $("#roadmapR").submit();
});

$(".deleteChanges").on("click",function(){
  alert("The form with id 'roadmapD' is submitting.");
  $("#roadmapD").submit();
});
```

[**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/QgoBdX?editors=1010)

Comment: That solves the problem of having the buttons inline. But I'd originally placed the buttons in separate forms since they were making different post actions. `save.html` versus `delete.html`. I don't see how the above solution can address this? Instead of jquery functions is ajax the right solution?